# Turn response of bash command into serialized json string

Tags: json, bash, serialization

I need to open the response of a bash command in a browser as a query params.

The idea is to run a bash command from my staffs computer and have it open a url in my new inventory app that does the rest for me.

Right now I have it working for just the serial. ie:

```
inventoryme(){
  OUTPUT="$(system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep Serial)"
  open "http://localhost:3000/?serial=${OUTPUT}"
}
```

Which opens: http://localhost.dev:3000/?serial=%20%20%20%20%20%20Serial%20Number%20(system):CENSORED

I can clearly parse this on my web app side, or do a better job in bash, but i'd love to turn the entire response of `prsystem_profiler SPHardwareDataType` into a json string!

Anyone have a good method or recommendation for this? The command returns something like this:

```
 Model Name: MacBook Air
      Model Identifier: MacBookAir7,2
      Processor Name: Intel Core i7
      Processor Speed: 2.2 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 2
      L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
      L3 Cache: 4 MB
      Memory: 8 GB
      Boot ROM Version: MBA71.0166.B06
      SMC Version (system): 2.27f2
      Serial Number (system): CONSORED
      Hardware UUID: CONSORED
```

Comment: Use `awk` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways to do it with Perl:

```
# JSON::PP should be available. JSON::XS is faster, but is not a core module
perl -MJSON::PP -ne '/(\S.*):\s*(.*)/ and $data{$1} = $2; END { print encode_json(\%data) }'

# If you don't have a JSON module installed
perl -ne '/(\S.*):\s*(.*)/ and $json .= "\"$1\": \"$2\","; END { chop $json; print "{ $json }" }'
```